# My JQuery removeClass and addClass wont work

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So im trying to learn to code with json, bootstrap, and jquery. I was trying to remove active class for all button when i click nav-link with `removeClass()` and then add the active class again when i click certain button in nav-link with `addClass()`, but it wont work in my code. Here is my code :

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" width="120"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler"
          type="button"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
          aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
          <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">All Menu</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pizza</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pasta</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Nasi</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Minuman</a>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row mt-3">
        <div class="col">
            <h1>All Menu</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row" id="daftar-menu">
        
    </div>
</div>
```

JS :

```
 $.getJSON('data/pizza.json', function(data) {
    let menu = data.menu;
    $('#daftar-menu').empty();
    //looping terhadap object 
    $.each(menu, (index, data) => {  //berikan tiap elemen pada menu sebuah fungsi
        $('#daftar-menu').append(`<div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card mb-4">
                <img src="img/menu/${data.gambar}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">${data.nama}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">${data.deskripsi}</p>
                <h5 class="card-title">${data.harga}</h5>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Pesan Sekarang</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>`);
    });
});

//everything works fine until this point
$('.nav-link').on('click', function() {
    $('.nav-link').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

even when i check it with alert, the alert wont work too. am i missing something?

Comment: I go with your code all things are fine

Comment: Hello. The jQuery to removeClass and addClass works as expected for me. (I tossed your code onto a WordPress page, adding just `jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) { /*code*/ }); Do you show any errors in console?

Comment: @JamesValeii oh really? so when i saved my code nothing happen in console, as well as the browser. so the code should make 'All Menu' active by default, and then inactive as the othe button pressed right? mine was the 'All Menu' still active even when i clicked the other button. even alert is not working when i write it below click event. i got the code from tutorial in youtube, but from video is working fine, but mine wasn't

Comment: Yes, I added the HTML and .nav-link toggle jQuery (within script tags and document.ready) to a WordPress content area. I was able to click different navigation items and class 'active' was removed and then class 'active' was added to $this.

Comment: @JamesValeii i literally have no idea why my code wont work lol

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code snippet. This sets the event to trigger on nav-links that gets added even after the code's execution.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.nav-link', function() {
    $('.nav-link').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: oh my god yes, it works. thank you very much